# Assessing clusterability of a dataset with Hopkins Statistics

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I would like to asses the clusterability of my dataset of over 80.000 variables with Hopkins stastics. I started with n= 80.000. As n is obviously too high I reduce it to 10. But still received the same error message:

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2511.3 Gb

> clustab <- get_clust_tendency(WKA_ohneJB, 10, graph = TRUE, gradient = list(low = "red",
>   +                                                                                 mid = "white", high = "blue"))

Apart from solving the issue, I have a further question: What is the highest number (n) you can take?

## 3. Import csv file

WKA_ohneJB <- read.csv("WKA_ohneJB.csv", header=TRUE, sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## 4. Verify structure

str(WKA_ohneJB)

## 5. Descriptive Statistics for column BASKETS_NZ

mean(WKA_ohneJB[,"BASKETS_NZ"]) # 1.023035

median(WKA_ohneJB[,"BASKETS_NZ"]) # 1

var(WKA_ohneJB[,"BASKETS_NZ"]) # 0.06871633

sd(WKA_ohneJB[,"BASKETS_NZ"]) # 0.262138

range (WKA_ohneJB[,"BASKETS_NZ"]) # 0 49

hist (WKA_ohneJB[,"BASKETS_NZ"])

## 6. Summary descriptive statistics

summary(WKA_ohneJB)

## 7. Assessing clusterability of data set

clustab <- get_clust_tendency(WKA_ohneJB, 10, graph = TRUE, gradient = list(low = "red",
                                                                                mid = "white", high = "blue"))

WKA_ohneJB$hopkins_stat

[image: pic csv file]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you get indicates a failure to obtain memory (more on [memory limits in R](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/Memory-limits)).

To increase the amount of memory allocated to R you can use [memory.limit](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/memory.size)

```
memory.limit(size = NA)
```

As mentioned in the documentation, *size* is

> numeric. If NA report the memory limit, otherwise request a new limit,
>   in Mb. Only values of up to 4095 are allowed on 32-bit R builds, but
>   see ‘Details’.

Reading *Details*

> If 32-bit R is run on most 64-bit versions of Windows the maximum
>   value of obtainable memory is just under 4Gb. For a 64-bit versions of
>   R under 64-bit Windows the limit is currently 8Tb.

Or simply use

```
memory.size(max = TRUE)
```

(If TRUE the maximum amount of memory obtained from the OS is reported)

So, if you have a 64-bit Windows 10, increasing the memory allocated should fix your problem.